# UINavigationController shows but without back button

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In my delegate class I have this -

```
BluenibViewController *mvc = [[BluenibViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *unvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[unvc pushViewController:mvc animated:NO];
[mvc release];
[self.window addSubview:unvc.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

and in my BluenibViewController I have this method -

```
-(IBAction) BookingsViewController:(id)sender

{
    bookingsViewController1 = [[BookingsViewController alloc]
                              initWithNibName:@"BookingsViewController"
                              bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
[navController pushViewController:bookingsViewController1 animated:YES];


self.title = @"Bookings";
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.view addSubview:bookingsViewController1.view];
[navController release];
[bookingsViewController1 release];
```

}

Ob click of this method I am able to go to the next view but there is no back button on the navigation bar.

Please point me to the silly mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see quite a few errors here.  Lets see if I can't be of some service.

First, I see that you're overreleasing your navigation controller [navController release];

Second, you should only have to make the window key/visible once in your entire project.  You set your navController as the rootViewController for your window, make it key/visible, and then you should never have to do anything with your window again.  Don't think it's breaking anything, but you should remove all calls to make key/visible beyond the first.

In the end, pushing a new view controller should look like this:

[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[BookingsViewController alloc] init] autorelease] animated:YES];

You shouldn't need anything else to get what you're looking for.

Comment: Steve, Thanks but it does nothing after I remove the [self.view addSubview:bookingsViewController1.view] line. It stays on the root controller.

Comment: Did you remove the extra [navController release] line?  That one was bothering me the most.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks a lot for pointing the mistakes. I made a fresh project and did as you said and it started to work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You should not add `unvc.view` as a subview of `self.window`.  You should just assign `unvc` as `self.window.rootViewController`:

```
self.window.rootViewController = unvc;
```

and you should not add `bookingsViewController1.view` as a subview of `self.view` (in your `BookingsViewController:` method).  The navigation controller will take care of getting `bookingsViewController1.view` onto the screen after you have pushed it.

Comment: Hey Rob, I added unvc as root view and removed the [self.view addSubview:messageViewController1.view];. But after doing this I can't get the subview at all. It just loads the navigation bar. And There is no back button yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton =YES;
```

Follow this code . Hope it helps ....

Answer (score 0):

it comes a little bit late but in iOS 8 you can do:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```